# Problem with Python Pandas data output to excel in date format

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, date

Need guidance on how I can  format a value to date format in `Pandas` before it prints out the value to an `Excel sheet`.

I am new to `Pandas` and had to edit an existing code when the values are output to an `Excel sheet`.
After some conditional/functional calculations are done, the value is then output to `Excel`.
My Current value seems to be in `string format` which is not an `Excel` friendly date format.

Output of the value looks like this :

[image: Output of the value looks like this]

Needed to format the output to the date format

[image: Needed to format the output to the date format]

I did try the options of `strptime`, but as per my understanding,  these values will also give the output in string format. the strange part is, I am not able to format the column in `Excel` to date format using `Excel` formatting option as well.

Thank you for your time and help.

My code is something like this:

---

```
def calculate(snumber,owner,reason):
    #some if conditions and then
    date11 = Date + relativedelta(months = 1)
    return date11.strftime('%d %b %Y')


df['date1'] = df.apply(lambda x: calculate(x['snumber'], x['owner'], x['reason']), axis=1)
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert date format in pandas dataframe itself using below:

```
date['date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date1'])
```

Example:

I have a dataframe

```
PRODUCT     PRICE   PURCHSE     date
0   ABC     5000    True    2020/06/01
1   ABB     2500    False   2020/06/01
```

apply above given formulae on date in dataframe

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

Output will like:

```
    PRODUCT     PRICE   PURCHSE     date
0   ABC     5000    True    2020-06-01
1   ABB     2500    False   2020-06-01
```

Answer (score 5):

For making sure you have column in dateformat, use following

```
df['date1'] = df['date1'].dt.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
```

Once that is done, you can use Pandas ExcelWriter's xlsxwriter engine.

Please see more details about that in this article: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_column_formats.html

```
# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("pandas_column_formats.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

# Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects.
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'dd/mm/yy'})

# Set the column width and format. 
# Provide proper column where you have date info.
worksheet.set_column('A:A', 18, format)

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```